# Connection cannot be null when hibenate.dialect not set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernateexception

I am new to J2EE application development, and I should write a simple project using hibernate, spring and struts together. I added facets to my project in myeclipse, and I configured my struts.xml, but I don't know why am I receiving this type of exception, I searched the internet but I could not understand where the problem is.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:189)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:350)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 36 more
```

My applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/enrollment">
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Classroom.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Enrollment.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Students.hbm.xml</value></list>
    </property></bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /><bean
    id="ClassroomDAO" class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.ClassroomDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="EnrollmentDAO"
    class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.EnrollmentDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="StudentsDAO" class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.StudentsDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean></beans>
```

I have edited applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    abstract="false" lazy-init="default" autowire="default"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/enrollment" p:username="root"
    p:password="root">
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml">
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Classroom.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Enrollment.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Students.hbm.xml</value></list>
    </property> -->
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /><bean
    id="ClassroomDAO" class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.ClassroomDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="EnrollmentDAO"
    class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.EnrollmentDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="StudentsDAO" class="com.rpkavosh.hibernate.StudentsDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean></beans>
```

and also I added a new hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools. -->
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/enrollment
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">Enrollment</property>
    <mapping resource="com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Classroom.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Enrollment.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/rpkavosh/hibernate/Students.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

but I still receive the same error. Any advise will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the database is up and running?

Comment: yes, from dbbrowser, I can find my table, I think it means database is up and running, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you can see the schema and the data then the database is definitely running

Comment: When I tried to use HQL editor, it shows me an error : Error Creating Configuration, Reason: LocalSessionFactoryBean Could not be created

Comment: I have never used HQL editor so I can't really give you any pointers on that

Comment: what about the main problem? can you help me why am I facing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set hibernate4 tomcat7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596896/connection-cannot-be-null-when-hibernate-dialect-not-set-hibernate4-tomcat7)

Comment: @NaeemBaghi which version of MySQL

Comment: @NaeemBaghi Also do you have dependency for this `<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.31</version>
   </dependency>`

Comment: I used MySQL5. no all I set is here in the applicationContext.xml which generated automatically.

Comment: @Jens I saw that question before, but I could not resolve the problem

Comment: @NaeemBaghi Can you try this: `<property name="hibernateProperties">
<value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</value>`</property>

Comment: I replaced the code but it didn't work :(